# Сумма данных в MySQL по ключевому полю с группировкой

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Уважаемые коллеги, доброго времени. Возник вопрос касательно запроса к БД. Я создал представление с полями:

- store_id
- type
- product
- amount

Данные дублируются по полю product.

[image: Представление]

Нужно сделать запрос, результатом которого, была бы таблица такой же структуры, но без дублирования продуктов, с указанием общего количества в поле amount или в доп. поле amount_extend.

Как реализовать данный запрос?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение:

```
SELECT *,SUM(amount) AS amount_extend FROM cscart_warehouse_shop_amount GROUP BY product
```